# CVS : Searching committed files on a specific date

Tags: linux, eclipse, cvs

Is there anyway i can search for a list of committed CVS files on a specific date ?

Im currently using opensuse with cvs command line, and also with Eclipse IDE for my Java stuffs.

Comment: [csv history options](http://cvsman.com/cvs-1.12.12/cvs_153.php#SEC153)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVS uses RCS for the backend.  So you can work through CVS, or directly through RCS on the repository files...

From **man cvs**:

> > *log options*
> >
> > -d dates
> >     Print information about revisions with a checkin date/time in the range given by the semicolon-separated list of dates. The date formats accepted are those accepted by the -D option to many other cvs commands (see node ‘Common options' in the CVS manual).
> >
> > Dates can be combined into ranges as follows:
> >
> > d1<d2
> >
> > d2>d1
> >
> > Select the revisions that were deposited between d1 and d2.
> >
> > <d
> >
> > d>
> >
> > Select all revisions dated d or earlier.
> >
> > d<
> >
> > >d
> >
> > Select all revisions dated d or later.
> >
> > d
> >
> > Select the single, latest revision dated d or earlier.
> >
> > The > or < characters may be followed by = to indicate an inclusive range rather than an exclusive one.
> >
> > Note that the separator is a semicolon (;).

And similarly from the **man rcs** page...

So, you know, try:

```
% cvs log -d '2007/01/01<2008/07/07' .
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Just tested it, and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Eclipse CVS ChangeLog Plugin

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/changelog/